# Share via Whatsapp from browser: ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

Tags: android, url, redirect, share, whatsapp

I am trying to share via Whatsapp from the mobile browser.
My code is currently working on most devices, but some devices (mainly Samsung S-series) display an error the first time.

ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

This is what my a-tag looks like:

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=My%20message" id="whatsapp" data-action="share/whatsapp/share">
     Share on WhatsApp now
</a>
```

Should be easy right?

On iPhone and most Android devices this works fine. 
But there are some devices that initially display the above mentioned error. If you hit the back-button it does seem to redirect you to Whatsapp.

I think it has to do with Chrome, but not on all devices using Chrome give this error.

So I am lost, anyone who knows what goes wrong?

Comment: Sometimes i faced the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Some apps than embed a WebView (or equivalent) are not aware how to manage the scheme "whatsapp://".

You can make a fix: point the anchor to a web page that redirects to a URL with "whatsapp://" protocol.

Example:

Instead of

```
<a href="whatsapp://send?text=Some+Text">
```

you can do this:

```
<a href="http://yourserver/script?text=Some+Text">
```

And, in the server side, your script should fire a http redirect pointing to a "whatsapp url", for example, in PHP:

```
<?php
$inputText = sanitize_the_input_as_you_wish($_GET['text']);
header("Location: whatsapp://send?text=$inputText");
```

I've tested with recent versions of Chrome and Firefox mobile, it works.